# How does Gatling make size assertions on responsebody

Tags: inputstream, gatling, assertion, scalar

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
I have a file download function. In JMeter, i can use Size Assertion to assert the size of ResponseBody. Does anyone know how to implement it in Gatling? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some code samples of what it is that you have tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to very exactly.

Just body binary length? => use a `header` check and verify the Content-Length header.
Body integrity => use a `md5` or `sha1` check

Comment: Thanks, this is a good way, but I want to get the size of the ResponseBody, and then judge.
My complete code is as follows

Comment: val scn = scenario("downloaddemo")
     .exec(http("request_0")
         .post("/download/video")
         .headers(headers_0)
         .body(RawFileBody("bodies/gatlingdemo/downloaddemo/0000_request.dat"))
         .check(bodyBytes.saveAs("bodyByes"))
     )
     .exec(session=>{
         println("bodyByes size: "+session("bodyByes").as[Array[Byte]].length)
         session
     })

Comment: I tried the following code, but what the check method needs is a parameter of type HttpCheck, which obviously doesn't work. .check(bodyBytes.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]].length >= 10000).

Comment: Use transform: https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#http-check-transform

Comment: .check(bodyBytes.transform(_.length).gte(10000))

Comment: FYI, next Gatling 3.5.0 will have an optimized bodyLength check: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4015